# Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: java, android, gradle, fragmentmanager

I found the message Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager ( )' I want to add a fragment in an activity

here is my code

```
package com.formation.testfragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.*;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
}
```

here is my build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {


    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.formation.testfragment"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
```

but the method getSupportFragmentManager ( ) not found.
Thank you.

Comment: are u extending android.app.Activity instead of android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity?

Comment: show us your code

Comment: You need to extend AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 2):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is a method on `FragmentActivity`. You need to inherit from it — either directly or indirectly (e.g., by extending `AppCompatActivity`).

In your case, given your dependencies, you could extend `FragmentActivity` directly:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Answer (score 2):

You can found from the [FragmentActivity  documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity#getsupportfragmentmanager) that `getSupportFragmentManager` is a method of FragmentActivity. Usually, current Android project is using support appcompat library where you have AppCompatActivity. AppCompatActivity is derived from FragmentActivity. So, you can use either FragmentActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

or using AppCompatActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is 1 of the method from FragmentActivity

try this

`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`

The use of the method `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Normally people will do like this, to switch the fragment

[read more about fragment activity](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments) Here is the *Link* to read more about `fragment`

```
// Begin the transaction
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
// or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
// Complete the changes added above
ft.commit();
```

**R.id.frameLayout** is the id from `<frameLayout>` in your Layout xml file.

*Example:*

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extend your class to AppCompatActivity i.e,`public class MainActivity extends Activity` to `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`